# When does socket poll (selectwrite polling mode) become false?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

The return value of Socket.Poll Method as what is written in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.poll.aspx):

> The status of the Socket based on the polling mode value passed in the
>   mode parameter.
>
> Mode: SelectRead
>
> Return Value:
>   true if Listen has been called and a connection is
>   pending;
>
> -or-
>
> true if data is available for reading;
>
> -or-
>
> true if the connection has been closed, reset, or terminated;
>
> otherwise, returns false.

it appears to me that socket.poll method will always return true... I'm confused. it seems sensible for poll method to return true for the first two reasons stated but as for the third reason (true if the connection has been closed, reset, or terminated;), shouldn't it return false? what is the reason for poll to return true for the reasons mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that third case is that you can detect a client (or the server if you are on the client side) disconnecting, do your application-level cleanup, and then close that socket, thus releasing associated OS resources.

Comment: Then, how will I be able to tell if that's the case?

Comment: You try to read from the socket. If that fails then there's an error.

Comment: Then the poll is useless since I still have to read from the socket to see if it's disconnected.

Comment: Not totally useless, it tells you that some event has happened - you have to figure out which one. Otherwise you would not know the connection is gone.

Comment: maybe you can help me out with my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317452/the-bytes-my-server-program-receives-is-incomplete-why-im-using-c-sharp-net#comment11754870_9317452