# The bytes my server program receives is incomplete. Why? I'm using C# .net sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, filestream

This doesn't always happen. But it happens more often than receiving the bytes completely.

This is how my client prog sends bytes to my server prog:

```
public void sendBytes()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    TcpClient cli = tcpServer; //tcpServer is a global TcpClient variable I use to connect to the server. 
    NetworkStream ns = cli.GetStream();

    CopyStreamToStream(fs, ns, null);
    ns.Flush();
}

public static void CopyStreamToStream(Stream source, Stream destination, Action<Stream, Stream, Exception> completed)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[0x1000];
    int read;

    while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) // <- client loop
        destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

This is how my server prog receives bytes from my client prog:

```
FileStream ms = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
do
{
    int szToRead = s.Available; //s is a socket
    byte[] buffer = new byte[szToRead];

    int szRead = s.Receive(buffer, szToRead, SocketFlags.None);
    if (szRead > 0)
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, szRead);            
}
while(s.Available != 0); //i also tried ms.length < size_of_file_to_be_received_in_bytes
```

i stepped into the program and watched the values, and I don't know what causes the lack of bytes received. I don't know if the problem is with the client prog or the server prog.

i don't know if this is relevant, but when i tried stepping into the client loop (to watch the value of fs.length and check if it will be received in the server), all 4 attempts to send a file from the client to the server succeeded. but when i did not watch the client loop, and only watch the server app (to see the value of ms.length), only 1 of 4 attempts to send a file to the server succeeded. on the 3 failed attempts, ms.length is less than the bytes of the source file (i checked it in the file's property).

[This](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/228973/page2) is where I based this from

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

On the original code (from the website I based my program), the loop has a different condition:

```
FileStream ms = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
do
{
    int szToRead = s.Available; //s is a socket
    byte[] buffer = new byte[szToRead];

    int szRead = s.Receive(buffer, szToRead, SocketFlags.None);
    if (szRead > 0)
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, szRead);            
}
while(SocketConnected(s)); // <--- i changed this in my program

private static bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
{
    return !(s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && (s.Available == 0));
}
```

I think the SocketConnected tests if the socket is still connected because the original code for the client program was this:

```
CopyStreamToStream(fs, ns, null);
ns.Flush();
ns.Close();
```

i removed the ns.Close() from the program because I want to maintain the connection of the client application to the server. So I want to be able to check if I'm done reading all the bytes coming from the client app without closing the socket connection from the client side.

Comment: Have you considered using `Stream.CopyTo()` [assuming you're on .NET 4.0] ?

Comment: I'd like to recommend you using [Stream.CopyTo Method (Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) instead of  `CopyStreamToStream` function.

Answer (score 4):

If Available is zero this does not mean that you have finished reading bytes. It means that currently, in this nanosecond, there are no bytes queued. How could the server know how many bytes will be coming in the future?

In good approximation, every singe use of Available is an error!

Delete all usages of Available. Instead, always try to read a full buffer. If you get 0 this means the socket has been closed and you are done.

Edit: Here is some canonical read code:

```
var buffer = new byte[8192];
while(true) {
 var readCount = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
 if (readCount == 0) break;
 outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}
```

Comment: @usr I'm sorry. I'm not sure how I am supposed to "read a full buffer". Can you somehow provide a sample code on how to do that?

Comment: in my code i have:
`do { if (szRead > 0) ms.Write(buffer, 0, szRead); }while(s.Available != 0);`

and i changed it to this:

`do
{ if (szRead > 0) ms.Write(buffer, 0, szRead); else break; } while(true);`
will that do?

Comment: Try it. At least you got rid of Available which I hate. I think you can just take my code. It should work.

Comment: Not too long ago I made a simple sockets application, as I remember the last byte send over the socket was \0
this is the terminator for the array of bytes that's send over the connection

Comment: No that would mean that you couldn't send arbitrary data over a socket. Any data at all can be sent. The length/termination information must be encoded by the app itself.

Comment: When a socket indicates that data is available, but `Read` returns `0`, you've reached the end of stream. But I don't see why @usr dislikes `Available`. It's useful for non blocking, single threaded IO.

Comment: @Thomas there is no special meaning of \0 on a socket, especially if that socket is using a binary protocol where 0 is normal data.

Comment: Usr: good answer; just to say there is one potential use of Available (but yes, it should usually be avoided) - it can be useful to decide whether to do a sync vs async read. However, an even better approach may be the ReceiveAsync API which does this check internally and automatically.

Comment: Personally, I prefer a fully async read "loop" here (of course, it is no-longer a loop as such). Scales better: you don't need a thread per active connection.

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree fully. This is a use-case I was not aware of. Although I still never would have used it now that I know of this technique. I guess it is useful for latency-sensitive apps. In general I just read entire blocks (potentially asynchroneously).

Comment: i still haven't solved this problem. please help me out. i made a thread about his here: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/412831 ---- you will see the flow of my program there better. i hope than you can help me with this.

Comment: You are still using Available. As long as you don't get rid of that I refuse to help further.