# How to properly send and receive bytes/files using sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, byte

I have a client and server program. The client sends a file to the server by first converting the file to bytes and then send it to the server. The server will then reconstruct the file using the bytes it receives. I am having a problem with the server program. Sometimes, the bytes it receives are incomplete.

Now, I have already searched through the internet and found out that it is a common problem among beginner programmers like myself. I have tried various solutions that I found but nothing worked. (I've been working on this for about 2 days already)

I was wondering what is the proper way of sending and receiving files/bytes between two programs in a LAN? (One being the server and the other is the client, though of course, there can be more than 1 client program that will connect to the server program)

I hope someone can help solve this problem. Please... I hope someone who is well-versed in socket programming and about bytes can provide helpful information on this.

*Some extra information:
I actually based my code from this forum topic: [DANIWEB](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/228973). Reading through the thread, the program worked perfectly and even managed to send a 400MB+ video file. In my case, I'm only sending small images and document files less than 10mb in size and my server program fails more often that it succeeds.*

*I already asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317452/the-bytes-my-server-program-receives-is-incomplete-why-im-using-c-sharp-net#comment11754870_9317452) related to this problem, tried the answer given to me but my program still fails. I also found something in [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/csharplanguage/thread/C9633813-CA73-4F1B-B1D2-8BAE82BA1E35) that is a little similar to the answer given to me in my question. Tried it as well, but my server program still fails.*

Answer (score 2):

You say "incomplete" - this usually points to one of two things:

- the sender may have "nagle" enabled, and the last few bytes may still be held at their end (OS/NIC) until a large enough packet is available. Meaning: even though they called Send/Write/etc - it still hasn't left the client machine. This is not unexpected. They can force it to send by closing the socket (or at least, a send-shutdown), or by disabling nagle (set NoDelay = true) and taking responsibility for not fragmenting too much (BufferedStream can be useful for this)
- the receiver does not always get entire frames; at any Read/BeginRead/ReceiveAsync/etc all you are guaranteed is "some bytes" or "EOF". As such, you must keep reading until you have a compete frame. The question then, is, how is a frame defined by your protocol? Common approaches are length-prefixed (or length in a header), or a special frame-termination sequence

It is impossible to interpret more without code; however, as noted in another answer - it may help to offload the socket details to a library. As it happens, I'm working on one currently that I intend to release to OSS pretty soon.

Comment: if there are still a few bytes left in the sender, won't flush() force it to go to the server?

btw, the code for the application i'm talking about in this question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317452/the-bytes-my-server-program-receives-is-incomplete-why-im-using-c-sharp-net#comment11754870_9317452

please take a look at it and see what's wrong.

Comment: @Xel Flush doesn't work on TCP streams. But I don't think nagle should delay delivery for more than a few seconds, and even that only if packets are lost. Normally only games/latency critical applications need to disable nagle.

Comment: @Xel CodeInChaos is absolutely right that Flush() does nothing here, but I should add that...

Comment: ... (and /cc @CodeInChaos) I have yet to find any scenario that had dropped to the Socket level, but which was **not** latency-critical. And games would commonly go a step further, by using UDP, not TCP.

Comment: @Xel your sample code is fundamentally broken; it exits as soon as there is nothing buffered locally (Available). Frankly, you shouldn't even look at this property, unless you want to choose between a sync/async read (I.e. sometimes you might read sync while data is buffered locally, then switch to async to avoid blocking)

Comment: I made a thread about this in daniweb. please take a look a it. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/412831

Comment: @Xel right; so now what **exactly** happens? What data is missing? Does the loop exit? Note: it won't exit unless the client closes the outbound stream. Hence the need for "framing" that I already mentioned... My guess is it gets all the data and then blocks indefinitely - for the simple reason that it **doesnt know** that it is the end. The only way to do that is to know, in advance, how much data is inbound, so you know when to stop. This is exactly what I mean by "framing".

Comment: @MarcGravell this is what happens. when my client program has written all the bytes to the socket, the server gets doesn't get the last byte. it gets stuck in the socket.receive(). it seems that even though the client program has written the last byte to the stream, the server doesn't receive it

Comment: @Xel what makes you think it hasn't got it? Keep track of the total bytes read, and write that (debug/console/whatever) after every read. My suspicion is that all the data has been read, and it is waiting on **more** data, since the outbound isn't closed.

Comment: @Xel keep in mind: the receiver cannot tell (it is impossible) the difference between "the client has sent everything it wants to, and is waiting for a reply" from "the client is busy sending data, and some packets are taking a while". Hence Read will block forever if a receiver asks for data that the sender doesn't send, and they don't close their stream.

Comment: @MarcGravell I did what you told me. here's the output. File size: 29696
Received: 8192
Received: 8192
Received: 8192
Received: 4103

therefore, 1017 wasn't received

Comment: @Xel and again I ask: is the client using nagle? How much does the client think it sent if you do the same thing?

Comment: @Xel also, in your sample you used a 1000 byte buffer, so... To be getting 8192 you've changed the code gain. This makes it quite hard to keep up and give a useful answer...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7884/discussion-between-xel-and-marc-gravell)

Comment: @MarcGravell the client is not using nagle

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer, I strongly recommend you a Socket Framework on .net platform. It will save you lots of time to develop by yourself.
[SuperSocket](http://SuperSocket.Codeplex.com)